# Issue using User defined parameter in Build Feature teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

I have template which have two build steps:

1. Maven
2. Command line

Command line steps sets current datetime in variable which i want to use in Build Feature.

I am getting proper Current datetime as follows via Command Line step:

```
#!/bin/bash
export current_build_date_format="+%%d%%m%%Y_%%H%%M%%S"
export current_build_date="$(date $current_build_date_format)"
##teamcity[setParameter name='current_build_date' value='$current_build_date']
```

When i am trying to refer it in Build Feature, its not able to identify parameter via `"%current_build_date%"`

It shows paramter as undefined in `Configuration Parameter section`

[image]

Anything missing? I have defined that parameter via command line, how will teamcity features use that

Parameter error:

[image]

Error while reading user defined parameter first:

```
Initialization
[05:42:27][Initialization] - Build Details Validator
[05:42:27][ Build Details Validator] Error: Conversion = 'm'
[05:42:27][Initialization] Build validation failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo TeamCity service message to let TeamCity parse and use it, e.g.:

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='current_build_date' value='$current_build_date']"
```

Comment: when i echo and try to use in buildFeature, it fails in agent compatibility

Comment: 1. So, "echo" sets parameter correctly? 2. What Build Feature are we talking about, actually? 3. How it fails in agent compatibility?

Comment: i am setting build version using Build Parameters Feature. Once i use that parameter i set above as %current_build_date% is not able resolve. I see in my Build parameters if i dont use in build feature. get error as in screenshot

Comment: If I get it right, the problem is you're trying to use parameter without defining it: you set it while build is running, but TeamCity has no idea that you're doing it this way. You can `Edit` parameter in `Configuration Parameter` section and add some value — it will be replaced by actual value by setParameter during build time.

Comment: your thinking is right, let me try your suggestion.

Comment: one more issue i am facing is i am creating version name using three parameters, two are defined by me and one is through maven. if i put maven in between while creating version it fails.

Fails: %myparameter1%-%maven.project.version%-%myparameter2%
works: %maven.project.version%-%myparameter1%-%myparameter2%

want version to be like failed one

Comment: Could you describe "it fails" in more details? You got any errors? Or some kind of unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Error added in question above

Comment: No ideas. Looks like a separate question, some details on what values your parameters might have could help (in case there's some parsing problem)